# How can I mount a Wicket application at /* in GAE development server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket, stack-overflow

My Wicket application runs fine on the live Google App Engine at /*

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WicketApplication</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However this URL pattern does not work on the development server (GAE 1.2.8): a request to http://localhost:8080/ gives this message:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

RequestURI=/
Caused by:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1451)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:365)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.removeAttribute(Dispatcher.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:379)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.removeAttribute(Dispatcher.java:399)
...
```

There are no other servlets in the web.xml which could interfere, so maybe it is a known problem?

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar kind of problem in OC4J, look at my solution [here](http://webmoli.com/2009/11/22/wicket-in-oc4j-oracleas/).